# How do I disable logging for a specific dependency in SBT?

Tags: scala, sbt, slf4j, logback, slick

I have the following build.sbt file:

```
version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.10.0-RC1"

scalacOptions := Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation", "-encoding", "utf8")

resolvers ++= Seq(
  "sonatype releases" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/",
  "sonatype snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/",
  "typesafe repo" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/",
  "spray repo" at "http://repo.spray.io/"
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "io.spray"           %   "spray-can"         % "1.1-M4.2"
  ,"io.spray"          %   "spray-routing"     % "1.1-M4.2"
  ,"io.spray"          %   "spray-testkit"     % "1.1-M4.2"
  ,"io.spray"          %%  "spray-json"        % "1.2.2"     cross CrossVersion.full
  ,"com.typesafe.akka" %%  "akka-actor"        % "2.1.0-RC1" cross CrossVersion.full
  ,"org.specs2"        %%  "specs2" % "1.12.2" % "test"      cross CrossVersion.full
  ,"com.typesafe"      %   "slick_2.10.0-RC1"  % "0.11.2"
  ,"com.h2database"    %   "h2"                % "1.3.166"
  ,"org.xerial"        %   "sqlite-jdbc"       % "3.6.20"
  ,"org.slf4j"         %   "slf4j-api"         % "1.6.4"
  ,"ch.qos.logback"    %   "logback-classic"   % "1.0.7"
  ,"org.specs2"        %   "specs2_2.10.0-RC1" % "1.12.2"    % "test"
  ,"junit"             %   "junit"             % "4.8.1"     % "test"
)
```

How do I enable DEBUG level reporting for my own (the current) project, but disable it for another. In this case I don't want to see the Slick library's debug output, but still want to see debug logging for my own project.

Comment: In log4j.xml you can configure log level for each library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your logback.xml add an entry like this:

```
<logger name="com.typesafe.slick" level="INFO"/>
```

This means, that when a logger is obtained by any class of the namespace `com.typesafe.slick` it will have `INFO` set as log level.

edit: Here's the link to the [documentation](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html).

Comment: Cool thanks. I did that and it works. I was just hoping it was possible to keep course grained logging inclusions/exclusions as part of the SBT setup to avoid spreading settings in different files. For example, in SBT you set the runlevel e.g. test, or runtime, and in the same fashion it would have been nice to just tell it to set the log level for a library.

Comment: I don't think that is possible. Setting the log level is runtime configuration, but sbt can only affect compile time. Also you have to have a logback.xml anyway, so I don't see the benefit of adding more stuff to the build file.

Comment: I suppose it depends on the way you use SBT. It's not uncommon to set the name and location of the logback.xml file as part of SBT config, which can be used to achieve the desired effect. I was just hoping to simplify my setup a little.

Comment: It's worth noting that as of today (16/1/13) the correct name is "scala.slick", rather than "com.typesafe.slick"

Comment: Following  AlecZorab's comments the name is no longer 'scala.slick' but just 'slick'

Answer (score 0):

To see what name the logger of you dependency have you can use the standard logging appender in your `logback.xml`. So if you have the following:

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{1000} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

You will get something like as a log message:

> 12:53:09 [AmexReporting-akka.stream.default-blocking-io-dispatcher-6]
>   INFO  **net.schmizz.sshj**.connection.channel.direct.SessionChannel -
>   Will request `sftp` subsystem

Then you can add a logger between the appender and root level configuration:

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{1000} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="net.schmizz.sshj" level="OFF"/>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Where the logger name is a part or the full package name that you can see in the log output, depending on how granular you want your log settings to be.