# Akka cluster: how to disable ClusterHeartbeat log

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

I'm playing a bit with an Akka cluster and I had a setup with 2 nodes. As expected, the two nodes chat each other to say that they are alive through the *heartbeat*. So every second I have a string like this in my log

```
[debug] 15:42:10.683-a.c.ClusterHeartbeatSender: Cluster Node  
[akka.tcp://application@127.0.0.1:52650] - 
Heartbeat to   [akka.tcp://application@127.0.0.1:2551]
```

However I wouldn't like to see this diagnostic, since it hides my debug information and I'm quite sure that the cluster works since is made up of two JVMs on my machine. I tried to change the configuration with

```
akka.cluster.log-info = off
```

but it does not seem to work for this case. How can *hide* this info from logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved using [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13287464/1360888) about changing log level for a specific class or package. I leave question and answer for future reader looking for quick solution. In my case I added this row

```
<logger name="akka.cluster.ClusterHeartbeatSender" level="OFF"/>
```

to root of `logger.xml` file